# How to use AngularJS's scope values to generate custom html tag's attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to embed a google map's iframe to my project, one per restaurant. The problem is that if the value of the addres is in:

```
$scope.restaurant.address
```

And I have to insert this code:

```
        <iframe width="450" height="250"
       src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_KEY&q={{restaurant.address}}">
       </iframe>
```

{{restaurant.address}} is not correctly interpreted, and when the link is generated instead of the proper address, {{restaurant.address}} appears.

Any clue? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried ngSrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
app.controller('SomeController', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.restaurant.address = '1313 Mockingbird Ln.';
    $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_KEY&q=" + $scope.restaurant.address);
});
```

HTML:

```
<iframe width="450" height="250" ng-src="{{url}}"></iframe>
```

You can read more about `ngSrc` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

`$sce` is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce